# How to submit form via POST with Angular 1.5.8 and Java Servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp, servlets

I read some tutorials and online doc but still can't figure it out.
I want to pass some params from jsp form. 
This is my js script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FormController', FormController);

//add dependecies
FormController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function FormController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.blob = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/javaAngularJS',
            data : $scope.blob,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        });
    };
}
```

This is my form:

```
<div class="site-body" ng-app="myApp">
    <form ng-controller="FormController" ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <p>Blob Key: <input type='input' name='blob-key' ng-model="blob.key"></p>
    <p>Ancestor: <input type='text' name='ancestor' ng-model="blob.ancestor"></p>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</div>
```

I have a Servlet Class with Post method added to my web.xml. I'm able to use Angular and AJAX calls with other stuff but i'm stuck with this.
How can i retrieve correctly my form params in the Servlet?For example i want to print params with System.out.prinltn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike) service for serializing your data.

( from `{key: "asd", ancestor: "asd"}` to `ancestor=asd&key=asd` )

```
FormController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'];

function FormController($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  $scope.blob = {};
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http({
       method : 'POST',
       url : 'javaAngularJS', // use relative
       data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.blob),
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
       }
     });
   };
}
```

So you can get paramaters :

```
String key = request.getParameter("key");
String ancestor = request.getParameter("ancestor");
```

If you want to parse request with JSON format, then you can use Jackson, Gson etc. libraries which convert JSON input into Java objects and vice versa.